# VBA Selecting Column Corresponding to Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a little rusty with VBA and am having a complete mindblank. To spare you the entireity of my code, I'm trying to do one really simple thing:

Given cell "D7", I need to select the entire column corresponding to that cell. My first thought was

```
.range("D7").columns.select
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: `.Range("D7").EntireColumn.Select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.Range("D7").EntireColumn.Select
```